# How to declare and use a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I am wondering how I should declare a function in a jQuery script.

What I've got now:

```
function adjust_menu() {
                alert("test test");
        };
```

but when I call it like this:

```
("#first_link").click(function() {
            adjust_menu();
       });
```

it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you give here works just fine. I just tested it.

Comment: @shoebox639 You didn't add a $? :)

Comment: I most certainly did. and staring at the code again, that was the problem. lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be a typo, but you're missing the `$` before the jQuery selector, and you need to be sure the DOM is ready before running this code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#first_link").click(function() {
         adjust_menu();
    });
});
```

Doing `$(function() { ... });` is a shortcut for [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which makes sure the DOM is ready before your code runs. Selecting `first_link` does no good if it doesn't exist yet. :o)

Answer (score 4):

Unless it's a typo, you're missing the `$` or `jQuery` at the start:

```
$("#first_link").click(function() {
  adjust_menu();
});
```

Or a bit shorter, and maintaining context:

```
$("#first_link").click(adjust_menu);
```

In any case, you should be seeing an error in your console (provided you're executing this when `#first_link` is present (e.g. `document.ready)), always check your console to see what's blowing up.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Since you we're all saying the same, you were all being right. But now the following has happened: the thing runs in Chrome(ium), but FireFox tells me that adjust_menu is undefined?

Comment: Oh sorry! Nevermind. Found the bug :) Using VIM for the first time, and it's hard :P

Comment: But, what if I want to call adjust_menu() without a selector. I don't want $("#first_click").click(adjust_menu), I want the function being called without the click.

Comment: @Sammy - In that case just do `adjust_menu()`

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'm being a bit of a noob here. That works (of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Your problem is definitely that you forgot the `$` or `jQuery` before you used jQuery.

Also you can just do `("#first_link").click(adjust_menu)`

Comment: Not my downvote - but this wouldn't resolve any problem, though it's better in most respects...it wouldn't really solve any error compared to the original code.