# How to declare a function in JQuery and reference from external .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to work out an example from [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211032/ajax-nonce-with-check-ajax-referer) that I do not have enough reputation to comment on (which would have probably have been better than asking a new question)

I've included the following snippit in my `login.js` code as in the linked example.

```
function send_stuff_to_server(){

var data = {
    'action': 'handle_login', // missed this same as your action hook wp_ajax_{handle_login}
    'security': MyAjax.security // We can access it this way
}

$.post(MyAjax.ajax_url, data, function (callBack) {
      console.log(callBack); // Will return nonce
});

}
```

**HTML/PHP front end**

Following [another example as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947263/using-an-html-button-to-call-a-javascript-function) a guide, I'm just making a simple button that will allow me to test the `send_stuff_to_server` function defined in the external script.

```
<!--Creating Nonce Here as example-->
<input type="hidden" name="login_nonce" value="<?= wp_create_nonce('login_nonce'); ?>"/>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme">

<script>
//- Using a function pointer:
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = send_stuff_to_server;
//- Using an anonymous function:
//document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function () { alert('hello!'); };
</script>
```

When I click the button and check the console, I get an error that suggests $ is a problem.

I have tried passing in this jQuery related 'thing' using `function send_stuff_to_server($)` and it still isn't happy.

I don't want to use an anonymous function and then define the button onclick action in the external script ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092229/how-to-declare-and-use-a-function-in-jquery)). I just want to resolve the JQuery namespace issue with $ and then be able to define the on click method in the the font end code as I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling a bit silly about this, but the solution was to replace the `$.post` with `jQuery.post`.